# Angular object to regular object without $$state

Tags: angularjs

Using angular an object is created. I want to use this object somewhere else and am trying to convert this object to a regular object without the $$state in it. I already tried `angular.toJSON(obj)`, but no success.

Below how the object is from angular

```
d {
    $$state: {
        status: 1
        value: {
            config: Object
            data: {
                data: Array[253]
                languages: Object
                total: 253
            }
            __proto__: Object
            headers: (c)
            status: 200
            statusText: "OK"
            __proto__: Object
            __proto__: Object
            error: (a)
            success: (a)
            __proto__: Object
        }
    }
```

I am only interested in the d:$$state:value:data array. How do I go about this?

I tried to `nData = JSON.stringify(data)` first and then `JSON.parse(nData)`, but then I only get an object $$state with status of 1 back. The rest is then lost it seems

Comment: How did you get this `d` object? It seems like the response object of a `$http` request.

Comment: Never mind :$ I shouldn't have sent the $scope.data, but just the data and then all works well

Comment: My back end saves everything I sent to it too. We don't trust them to validate data :D

Answer (score 0):

Never mind :$ I shouldn't have sent the $scope.data, but just the data and then all works well

```
            Property.getByCategory($scope.category, JSON.stringify($scope.filters)).success(function(data) {
                mapdata = data;
                $scope.total = data.total;
                $scope.properties = data.data;
                $scope.loading = false;
                $scope.lang = data.languages;
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.list ul li').responsiveEqualHeightGrid();
                }, 1000);
            });
```